# Android recycler view with 2 colums not aligned

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I try to create a recycler view with this kind of design

[image]

This is a single Recycler view, the tricky part is here

[image]

We are on the second row of the recycler view and I need to have the second row on the middle of the right element of the first row.

Here is the current code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1 "
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_8"/>    

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1 "
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_8"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Is it possible to doing this on Android ? I try to use negative margin for the left element of row but this is not working.

I'm using a recylcler view and a basic RecylcerView.Adapter for inflate the content.

Comment: Is this a set? I meant there will be similar items in this whole list right? Will Every set contain 5 boxes like its shown above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager) . [GridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager)  take equal space for each cell. Unlike `GridLayoutManager` ,`StaggeredGridLayoutManager` take space for each cell as much as they required.

You can use 2 view type for `RecyclerView`.

1. NormalView
2. View with extra top margin

Use 2nd view only for position 1. As only position 1 view contain extra top margin you will see 2nd column first item have some extra top  space. I think you can solve this way.

Override `getItemViewType` method

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    if (position == 1)
        return 1;
    return 0;

}
```

in `onCreateViewHolder` method

```
if (viewType == 0){
   // inflate your regular layout 
}else{
  // inflate layout with extra top margin  
}
```

Sample layout Xml:

regular layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"

>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/album_8"
        />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewSubTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="11sp" />

</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Layout with extra top margin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"

>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/album_8"
        />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewSubTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="11sp" />

</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Check this [repo](https://github.com/yousufshawon/AdvanceRecyclerView) for `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` example and some advance `RecyclerView` use.